# Intel Inspector: "Source file not found. Suggestion: Specify locations in a Project Properties dialog box search tab."

Tags: debugging, intel, intel-oneapi, intel-advisor

I'm building a small application to my phd research. As the application is presenting some undefined behavior, I decided to use the Intel Inspector standalone GUI to locate memory problems and it manage to find a considerably amount of problems as shown in the image below:

[image]

I'm using intelOneAPI compiler with the following options: `icx /Qstd:c17 /Zi /DEBUG /Qopenmp /O3 /Ot /Qipo src/main.c src/libs/edosystems.c src/libs/nldyn.c src/libs/iofiles.c src/libs/interface.c src/modules/time_series.c src/modules/poinc_map.c src/modules/lyap_exp_wolf.c src/modules/ftime_series.c`

I read the documentation and did some digging on google and I could not manage to find how to make the Intel Advisor to point the problematic lines in my source code. What am I missing here?

The main Project Properties:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to view the source code in Inspector or Vtune, use debugging symbols.

example:

Instead of using the below command

```html
g++ test cpp-o test
```

use:

```html
g++ test.cpp -g -o test
```

Then give that executable or binary to the Intel Inspector to view the source code.
[image]

Also, give a path to the source directory before starting any analysis.
[image]